Error while adding Google as OpenID Connect identity provider to AWS Cognito
I connected Google as OIDC identity provider to my AWS Cognito pool, but I am getting attributes required: [email] error when I try to sign in.
Authenticated call to https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo returns email  attribute:
{
    ...
    "email": "mail@example.com",
    ....
}

I had set up mapping between Cognito and OIDC provider (Google): email -> email. Email is also writable.
These are the scopes set up in Cognito: openid email phone profile and these in Google: openid .../auth/userinfo.email .../auth/userinfo.profile.
Do I understand it correctly that the error message is coming from AWS Cognito and means that Cognito is not getting email attribute from Google?
Any idea how to fix the error?
